# Copy data from one worksheet to another for dynamic lastrow

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop

I'm trying to copy data from Sheet1 (Column A and Column C) to Sheet2 (Column A and Column H).

[image]
[image]

Here is the Code that I have put together by searching online.

```
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet

Set ws1 = Sheet1
Set ws2 = Sheet2
Const WS1_COL = "A"
Const WS2_COL = "A"

Dim lr, b, c, i As Long
lr = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, WS1_COL).End(xlUp).Row

b = ws1.Range(WS1_COL & "3:" & WS1_COL & lr)

For i = 2 To lr - 1

    For c = 1 To lr - 1
        ws2.Range(WS2_COL & i & ":" & WS2_COL & i + 1).Value2 = b(c, 1)
    c = c + 1
    Next c

Next i
```

There is no error in the code - but it is only copying and pasting the last row for Sheet1.Column A to Sheet2.Column A, whereas I need it to copy every row until the last row. The lastrow for Sheet1.Column A is dynamic and will change every-week.

Any help is appreciated! Please bear in mind that I am new to VBA and have experience only with C++, and hence I can't seem to make the logic work.

Thanks for help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Version 1**

- Iterates through 2 sets of columns (iter 1: `ws1.A` to `ws2.A`, iter 2: `ws1.C` to `ws2.H`)
- Finds last row for each column copied
- Copies all values from Range to a variant array

  - iter 1: `ws1.A` (range with data) to `ws2.A` (empty)
  - iter 2: `ws1.C` (range with data) to `ws2.H` (empty)
- Iterates each value (row) in ws1 and copies it to same "row" in array for ws2
- Copies all values from array2 to Range on ws2

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub CopyColumns1()
    Const WS1_COLS = "A C"  'Columns to copy from
    Const WS2_COLS = "A H"  'Columns to copy to

    Dim ws1 As Worksheet:   Set ws1 = Sheet1
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet:   Set ws2 = Sheet2

    Dim cols1 As Variant:   cols1 = Split(WS1_COLS)     'Variant Array("A", "C")
    Dim cols2 As Variant:   cols2 = Split(WS2_COLS)     'Variant Array("A", "H")

    Dim c As Long, maxRows As Long, r As Long
    Dim lr1 As Long, arr1 As Variant, arr2 As Variant

    maxRows = ws1.Rows.Count    'Last Excel row (not to extract it multiple times)

    For c = LBound(cols1) To UBound(cols1)  'Iterate all columns in ws1 (synced with ws2)
        lr1 = ws1.Cells(maxRows, cols1(c)).End(xlUp).Row    'cols1 = Array("A", "C")

        'copy ranges to arrays, for speed
        arr1 = ws1.Range(ws1.Cells(2, cols1(c)), ws1.Cells(lr1, cols1(c))).Formula
        arr2 = ws2.Range(ws2.Cells(2, cols2(c)), ws2.Cells(lr1, cols2(c))).Formula

        For r = LBound(arr1) To UBound(arr1)    'Iterate all rows in ws1
            arr2(r, 1) = arr1(r, 1)             'Copy ws1.A to ws2.A, then ws1.C to ws2.H
        Next r  'row

        'moves the array to the range on ws2 (similar to paste, without cell formatting
        ws2.Range(ws2.Cells(2, cols2(c)), ws2.Cells(lr1, cols2(c))).Formula = arr2
    Next c      'column (iter 1: A to A, iter 2: C to H)
End Sub
```

---

**Version 2**

- Finds last row for all columns on `ws1` (based on UsedRange)
- Offsets the UsedRange lower by 1 row, to exclude the header (resizes by -1 row)
- Iterates through 2 sets of columns (iter 1: `ws1.A` to `ws2.A`, iter 2: `ws1.C` to `ws2.H`)
- Copies the entire columns in one operation, along with cell formatting

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub CopyColumns2()
    Const WS1_COLS = "A C"  'Columns to copy from
    Const WS2_COLS = "A H"  'Columns to copy to

    Dim ws1 As Worksheet:   Set ws1 = Sheet1
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet:   Set ws2 = Sheet2

    Dim cols1 As Variant:   cols1 = Split(WS1_COLS)     'Variant Array("A", "C")
    Dim cols2 As Variant:   cols2 = Split(WS2_COLS)     'Variant Array("A", "H")

    Dim c As Long, r As Long, lr1 As Long, ur1 As Range

    lr1 = ws1.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    Set ur1 = ws1.UsedRange.Offset(1).Resize(lr1 - 1)   '1 row lower, to exclude header

    For c = LBound(cols1) To UBound(cols1)  'Iterate all columns in ws1 (synced with ws2)
       ur1.Columns(cols1(c)).Copy ws2.Cells(2, cols2(c))   'Copy paste (with cell formats)
    Next c
End Sub
```

---

Answer (score -1):

code below will copy/paste everything from sheet1 column A to sheet2 column A and sheet1 column C to sheet2 column H excluding headers.

```
Sub copy_test()

    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet

    Set ws1 = Sheet1
    Set ws2 = Sheet2

    Ws1.range("A2",Ws1.range("A999999").end(xlup)).copy Ws2.range("A2")
    Ws1.range("C2",Ws1.range("C999999").end(xlup)).copy Ws2.range("H2")

End sub
```

Or for values only :

```
Sub copy_test2()

    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet

    Set ws1 = Sheet1
    Set ws2 = Sheet2

    ws2.Range("A2:A" & ws1.Range("A999999").End(xlUp).Row).Value = ws1.Range("A2", ws1.Range("A999999").End(xlUp)).Value
    ws2.Range("H2:H" & ws1.Range("C999999").End(xlUp).Row).Value = ws1.Range("C2", ws1.Range("C999999").End(xlUp)).Value

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks heaps! Works well !! :)